# How to wrap multiple grid container inside a React Fragment element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, grid, containers

Structure-
Suppose a `footer` element returning the following JSX and then I am using `footer` element inside a `LoginPage` element.

```
<React.Fragment>
[container1...(full width)]
[container2...(width- 60%)] [container3...(width- 40%)]
</React.Fragment>
```

I am aware with grid container and item concepts but here I want to wrap all container with an React `Fragment` elements for applying specific properties in footer element inside `LoginPage` file. How can I do that?

While I can convert all 3 containers in the items and then wrap inside a new container but this is not fulfilling my requirement

Please suggest other Material-UI layout container (if any)

Comment: Please define your issue.

Comment: The example code needs more context. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly clear what you're trying to do. If you want to pass props to your Footer, you can do so by spreading the props that you declare in LoginPage.js

LoginPage.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import Footer from "./footer";
    
    export default function SimpleContainer() {
      return (
          <Footer maxWidth="sm" style={{ height: "20vh" }}>
            More footer content
          </Footer>
      );
    }
```

Footer.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
    import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
    
    export default function Footer({ children, ...options }) {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Container {...options}>
            <Typography
              component="div"
              style={{ backgroundColor: "#cfe8fc", height: "100%" }}
            >
              Footer Container
            </Typography>
          </Container>
          {children}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

Demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-thsbg?file=/footer.js

If that's not what you're after feel free to expand